# Is it ok to not sign an iOS Debug app for internal use?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, signing

Since there are some issues with the ADP account and creating certificates, is it ok to not sign an iOS Debug app for internal use and install it in the internal devices through Xcode with signing turned off?

Comment: Yeah it is ok :)

Comment: How can you install the app with no certificates even that the debug build. You can use simulator if you don't have certificates yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to install unsigned apps on an iOS device, similarly if you want to use self-signed apps that use your own AppleID and not a proper ADC account have a limit of 7 days before you'll have to resign / reinstall them.
There is also a limit of how many apps of this nature you can install on any given device.

If these limits are no problem to you then really, I don't see why it wouldn't be OK for personal / internal use like that. Just be aware of the limitations.

Comment: Then how can I sign it for internal use even if it is a debug version. I can only create a Development Certificate due to the Developer Role I have on the team.